# why minimax don't choose the optimal solution in this situation

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, tic-tac-toe, minimax

im doing tictactoe project for cs50 course
when i was using minimax i find out the minimax in some situation couldnt find the optimal solution

here is my code :

```
"""
Tic Tac Toe Player
"""
import copy
import math

X = "X"
O = "O"
EMPTY = None


def initial_state():
    """
    Returns starting state of the board.
    """
    return [[EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY],
            [EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY],
            [EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY]]

board = initial_state()

def player(board):
    """
    Returns player who has the next turn on a board.
    """
    numO = 0
    numX = 0
    FirstPlayer = None
    for i in range(len(board)):
        for j in range(len(board[i])):
            if board[i][j] == O:
                numO += 1
            elif board[i][j] == X:
                numX += 1
    return X if numO == numX else O


def actions(board):
    """
    Returns set of all possible actions (i, j) available on the board.
    """
    possact = set()
    for i in range(len(board)):
        for j in range(len(board[i])):
            if board [i][j] == EMPTY:
                possact.add((i, j))
    return possact


def result(board, action):
    """
    Returns the board that results from making move (i, j) on the board.
    """
    boardcopy = copy.deepcopy(board)
    boardcopy[action[0]][action[1]] = player(board)
    return boardcopy
    

def winner(board):
    """
    Returns the winner of the game, if there is one.
    """

    for i in range(3):
        wonO = True
        wonX = True
        for j in range(3):
            if board[i][j] == O or board[i][j] == EMPTY:
                wonX = False
            if board[i][j] == X or board[i][j] == EMPTY:
                wonO = False
        if wonX:
            return X
        if wonO:
            return O

    for j in range(3):
        wonO = True
        wonX = True
        for i in range(3):
            if board[i][j] == X or board[i][j] == EMPTY:
                wonO = False
            if board[i][j] == O or board[i][j] == EMPTY:
                wonX = False
        if wonX:
            return X
        if wonO:
            return O

    diag1 = ''
    diag2 = ''
    j = 2

    for i in range(3):
      diag1 += str(board[i][i])
      diag2 += str(board[i][j])
      j -= 1

    if diag1 == 'XXX' or diag2 == 'XXX':
      return X
    elif diag1 == 'OOO' or diag2 == 'OOO':
      return O


def terminal(board):
    """
    Returns True if game is over, False otherwise.
    """
    if winner(board) == X:
        return True
    elif winner(board) == O:
        return True

    for i in range(len(board)):
        for j in range(len(board[i])):
            if board[i][j] == EMPTY:
                return False
    return True    

    
def utility(board):
    """
    Returns 1 if X has won the game, -1 if O has won, 0 otherwise.
    """
    resB = winner(board)
    if resB == X:
        return 1
    elif resB == O:
        return -1
    else:
        return 0


def minimax(board):
    """
    Returns the optimal action for the current player on the board.
    """
    if terminal(board):
        return None
    Max = float("-inf")
    Min = float("inf")

    if player(board) == X:
        return Max_Value(board, Max, Min)[1]
    else:
        return Min_Value(board, Max, Min)[1]

def Max_Value(board, Max, Min):
    move = None
    if terminal(board):
        return [utility(board), None]
    v = float('-inf')
    for action in actions(board):
        test = Min_Value(result(board, action), Max, Min)[0]
        Max = max(Max, test)
        if test > v:
            v = test
            move = action
        if Max >= Min:
            break
    return [v, move]

def Min_Value(board, Max, Min):
    move = None
    if terminal(board):
        return [utility(board), None]
    v = float('inf')
    for action in actions(board):
        test = Max_Value(result(board, action), Max, Min)[0]
        Min = min(Min, test)
        if test < v:
            v = test
            move = action
        if Max >= Min:
            break
    return [v, move]
```

here is the situation (computer played as O) :
[picture of 5th move](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srwnz.png)
the optimal solution is the bottom of the middle cell
but it chooses this : [picture of 6th move](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ird3N.png)
**The computer finally wins** but not in the optimal way

why minimax don't choose the optimal solution ?
and how can i fix it?

Comment: What is the *first step*  that your program does incorrectly, which leads (eventually) to the wrong result?

Comment: Have you tried running your debugger between the 5th and 6th moves?

Comment: @ScottHunter The program works properly it just didnt choose the fastest way to win

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not looked at whether your code correctly implements minimax, but I can explain why such results are to be expected.

There may be several paths through the game tree that lead to a node with the same utility value. The minimax algorithm does not make a distinction between quick wins and slow wins; it takes any path that results in a guaranteed win.

A common way to solve this is to assign a lower utility to slower wins. For example, set the utility of a win to `1000 - depth`. Conversely, the utility of a loss should be set to `-1000 + depth` to also make the algorithm prefer drawing out an unavoidable loss for as long as possible. (It's also good to keep the evaluation function symmetric in case you want to use [negamax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negamax).)

Answer (score 0):

you can add a win check before running the minimax algorithm, so when there is a possible win move it should choose it